# What is the easiest way to send GPS info to a server from a BADA OS phone?

Tags: mobile, gps, bada

Am currently developing a GPS powered solution for tracking field units, and I plan to use Samsung's BADA OS powered phones (affordable but powerful). The only problem am now facing, is i don't know the easiest way to obtain GPS info from the phone (a GT-S5333) to a server (probably via a GET). What can I do?

I've searched for available options and they might not be very friendly as this app doesn't even require an interface on the phone, just sending of the GPS info to a server. Samsung provides a C++ api for Bada (but I think this might be over-kill for this sort of task.)

The other option might be using Webwag's widget api, but I've tried it already, and it doesn't even seem to be possible to do anything beyond RSS widgets.

Might someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I did learn about the possibility of using J2ME's Location API, and indeed it is supported on Bada OS phones (virtually any modern phone). So I went for it, and this is how I would obtain my device's location:

> import javax.microedition.location.*;
>
> private String reportLocation(Form mainForm){
>
> Criteria cr= new Criteria();
>
> cr.setHorizontalAccuracy(500);
>
> final LocationProvider lp= LocationProvider.getInstance(cr);
>
> new Thread(){
>
> public void run(){
>
> lp.setLocationListener(PatrolGPSDevice.this, 30, -1, -1); 
>               }
>
> ```
>         }.start();
> ```
>
> Location l = lp.getLocation(60);
>
> Coordinates c = l.getQualifiedCoordinates();
>
> if(c != null ) {
>
> double lat = c.getLatitude();
>   double lon = c.getLongitude();
>
> //do what I want with the location data -- in this case, send it to a server
>
> }